# Launching a steam game from a Java program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program to open files and applications on my PC, now the problems only arise when I try to open a steam game (i.e. Planetside 2 or Terraria) from this program.  I have tried using Runtime, but that failed as well.  Here is where I am trying to open the game:

```j
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(path).toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e1) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If anyone can try to figure it out, it would be greatly appreciated!

This is the output error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: steam:\rungameid\218230 doesn't exist.
```

The path variable was "steam://rungameid/218230".

Comment: Post stack Traces in the question please

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)

Comment: Lets see what your var "path" equals, I think you need to include your entire file path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct the `Steam.exe` process to open your game by its `app id` or you can use the `steam` protocol:

```
import lombok.val;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class SteamGameExecutor
{
    public static final String STEAM_INSTALLATION_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe";
    private static final boolean USE_STEAM_PROTOCOL = true;

    public static void startGameById(String id) throws Exception
    {
        if (USE_STEAM_PROTOCOL)
        {
            val desktop = getDesktop();
            val steamProtocol = new URI("steam://run/" + id);
            desktop.browse(steamProtocol);
        } else
        {
            startProcess("-applaunch", id);
        }
    }

    private static void startProcess(String... arguments) throws IOException
    {
        val allArguments = new ArrayList<String>();
        allArguments.add(STEAM_INSTALLATION_PATH);
        val argumentsList = asList(arguments);
        allArguments.addAll(argumentsList);
        val process = new ProcessBuilder(allArguments);
        process.start();
    }
}
```

The protocol version should be more portable/platform-independent unless it doesn't exist on `Linux`/`Mac`.

To find the `app id` you can use [this](https://steamdb.info/search/) search. An implementation of finding the app id programmatically is for instance the following:

```
import lombok.val;

import java.io.IOException;

import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect;

public class SteamAppIdFinder
{
    private static final String SEARCH_URL = "https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app&q=";
    private static final String QUERY_SELECTOR = "#table-sortable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > a";

    public static String getAppId(String searchTerm) throws IOException
    {
        val completeSearchURL = SEARCH_URL + encode(searchTerm, UTF_8.name());
        val connection = connect(completeSearchURL);
        val document = connection.get();
        val selectedElements = document.select(QUERY_SELECTOR);
        val anchorElement = selectedElements.get(0);
        return anchorElement.text();
    }
}
```

Note that the second code snippet required [`JSoup`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup). Furthermore I'm using [`Lombok`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok) for the `val` keyword.